# Mail::send Parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sorry, but i'm new in laravel: 
Can't understand, for example in thi record:

```
Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data)
```

What does emails.contact is?

Thanks!

Comment: "emails.contact" is the view (template) of mail massage in which you transfer $data

Comment: resources/views/emails/contact is the way to this template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All information about Laravel send email messages. This will help you to understand how it works.

[Laravel - Sending Email](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_sending_email.htm)

And official documentation

[Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail)

**emails.contact** – name of the view that contains email message

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will use this recommendation :)